# In the USA do they test for covid while in transit?

Tags: usa, transit, covid-19

I'm taking a flight from YVR to SEA. My options are a direct flight (more expensive) or a flight that stops in SFO or PDX.

I'm going to take a PCR test prior to boarding but my question is, if I take a flight that stops, should I be wary of the connection time in case something goes wrong? Do they test me for COVID again?

Comment: Are you aware how short a flight this is?  The two cities are only about 200 km apart. Have you considered ground transportation options instead?  Any kind of connection will result in the journey taking much longer than it would just to travel by land - heck, even a direct flight, counting time spent at the airport, is probably longer.

Comment: @NateEldredge the land border isn't open to my knowledge

Comment: @Nate for some weird reason the US authorities think that the virus can only come from Canada via the land border. Moronic but that’s how the rules are setup.

Answer (score 4):

> should I be wary of the connection time in case something goes wrong?

No.

You need to show your test at check-in before boarding the first leg of your flight. Then you get your boarding passes and you are all set. There is no need to retest even if you miss your connection.

Test sample must be taken 3 days before departure (not arrival).

https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/testing-international-air-travelers.html